# Increment Badge Count

Tags: jquery, function, counter, parseint

```
jQuery.fn.add = function() {

    var Bnumber = $(this).find(".B_Add");

    if (Bnumber) {
        Bcount = parseInt(Bnumber.html()) + 1;
        $(this).find("div.B_Add").remove();
        $(this).parent().find(".B_List").append('<div class="Badge B_Add">'+ Bcount +'</div>');

    } else {
        $(this).find(".B_List").append('<div class="Badge B_Add">1</div>');
    }
}
```

I have a contextual menu script running, when i click on one of the options, it calls this function. It's supposed to see if the active element has this badge or not. If it does, it increments the integer value of the badge. Otherwise, it creates the badge starting at 1. The latter part is easy, the former harder.

I think i'm mixing up element types, and i'm not sure how to use parseInt...

*EDIT*

Figured it out.

```
jQuery.fn.add = function() {
    if ($(this).find(".Badge").hasClass(".B_add")) {
        bCount = parseInt($(this).find(".B_add").text());
        $(this).find(".B_add").remove();
        $(".OPT .B_list").append('<div class="Badge B_add">'+(bCount+1)+'</div>');
    } else {
        $(".OPT .B_list").append('<div class="Badge B_add">0</div>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
jQuery.fn.add = function() {

    var Bnumber = $(".B_Add");

    if (Bnumber) {
        var Bcount = parseInt(Bnumber.html()) + 1;
        Bnumber.html(Bcount);
    } else {
        $(this).find(".B_List").append('<div class="Badge B_Add">1</div>');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Bcount = parseInt(Bnumber.text()) + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my take on it:

```
jQuery.fn.add = function() {
    var badge = $('.B_Add', this);

    if (badge.length) {
        badge.html(Number(badge.html()) + 1);
    } else {
        $('.B_List', this).append('<div class="Badge B_Add">1</div>');
    }
}
```

1. Using the format `$('.B_Add', this)` for something inside of something else has always seemed the cleanest syntax to me.
2. You have to check for `badge.length` to see if an item was found - even when a jQuery selector matches no items, it still evaluates to `true`
3. There's no need to recreate the `B_Add` element, changing its content should accomplish the same thing.
4. I've never used `parseInt` in my life. `Number` seems to do the same thing, and it looks nicer.